# How to install Ubuntu next to Windows 7 on an encrypted Truecrypt system?

Tags: encryption, system-installation, truecrypt

Is there any way to install Ubuntu next to Windows 7 on an encrypted Truecrypt system?

Windows 7 is using the whole disk encryption. I know I can start from scratch and install both the systems, but I don't want to do that.

Using VMs is not an option either.

I would like to install Ubuntu 12.04 (in case it matters).

Comment: can't you disable truecrypt?

Comment: i need full disk encryption on both systems (-:

Comment: Encrypt windows partitions with 'TrueCrypt' and while installing ubuntu select the option 'Encrypt my home directory'!

Comment: I've been looking into this as well in the past (no luck...). So I ended up using a hard drive with hardware encryption. It saves a lot of hassle.